# Unable to find nltk_data when adding binary and data files

Tags: python, nltk, chatbot

I have a problem with exporting my python project. In this project, I am using the NLTK library, but when exporting it using the Pyinstaller tool the error mentioned in the title appears. I've been scouring a solution for weeks and I have not gotten an answer. I tried to use cx_freeze but other errors appear ... could anyone help me?

Tried use cx_freeze, and Pyapp.

'''Unable to find "/usr/nltk_data" when adding binary and data files.

Comment: If you downloaded [`nltk_data`](https://www.nltk.org/data.html) you may be able to add it to the path specified in the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problems editing the pyinstaller nltk-hook. After much research, I decided to go it alone in the code structure. I solved my problem by commenting on the lines:
`datas=[]`

`'''for p in nltk.data.path:
    datas.append((p, "nltk_data"))'''`

`hiddenimports = ["nltk.chunk.named_entity"]`

What's more, you need to rename the file: pyi_rth__nltk.cpython-36.pyc to pyi_rth_nltk.cpython-36.pyc . This file have 1 more underline. Warning with the python version.

Answer (score 0):

try making folder in your project /usr/nltk_data and there paste your nltk data.
do you have space in your username? avoid it.

```
nltk.download()
```

check the path there, or change it.

Comment: I tried this already. I'm using pycharm (env). So, everywhere he did not find my nltk_data folder I decided to put it there, but without success. See the complete log: Unable to find "/home/andras/PycharmProjects/Agent/venv/nltk_data" when adding binary and data files.

Comment: atleast you are not getting RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
 error like me.

Comment: try to remove any nltk.download()